# ActionbarSherlock 4.0 Deploy: what needs to be included?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I set up a test app using ActionbarSherlock 4.0, which works fine in the emulator.

In my test project, under Android Dependencies, the ABS .jar is listed as its location of the ABS library file on my computer's file structure. But where does this .jar file go for deployment of my test app to an actual device? How do I package the ABS stuff on my test app for deployment to a device? It does not seem to get copied over to my device.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But where does this .jar file go for deployment of my test app to an actual device?

It is automatically packaged into your APK file as part of the Android build process.

> How do I package the ABS stuff on my test app for deployment to a device?

It is automatically packaged into your APK file as part of the Android build process. You do not need to do anything special, given that it is listed as a dependency in your project.

Comment: Thanks. Clearly I'm doing something wrong then. I'll look into it when I get home.